# After upgrading to MAC OS 13(Ventura), an error occurred while installing curb (0.9.11), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, curb, macos-ventura

Not able to bundle install due to installation failed with curb 0.9.11. Was working fine with Mac OS 12, but after upgrading to ventura getting above error.

```
ERROR:  Error installing curb:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/ab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/curb-0.9.11/ext
/Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby -I /Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20221117-12107-158f8tb.rb extconf.rb
checking for curl-config... yes
checking for curlopt_tcp_keepalive... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-curl-dir
    --without-curl-dir
    --with-curl-include
    --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
    --with-curl-lib
    --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
/Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `block in try_compile'
    from /Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror'
    from /Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:52:in `block in have_constant'
    from /Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /Users/ab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
    from extconf.rb:44:in `have_constant'
    from extconf.rb:62:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/ab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/extensions/-darwin-21/2.6.0/curb-0.9.11/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

not getting successful bundle installation of curb 0.9.11 gem.

Comment: `You have to install development tools first.` After upgrading macOS you need to reinstall the developer tools. This can usually be done with `xcode-select —install`

Comment: @spickermann tried reinstalling but still not working.

Comment: How did you install it? Did the error message change after installing?

Comment: @spickermann used cmd xcode-select —install to install. same error msg.